# not getting integer type in elastic

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have been trying this for hours now. But this is not working as expected.

I am pushing data to elasticsearch via python script. Below are some fields I want as integers, but they are not being stored as integers. Sometimes, they are of None Type, else they are strings. So, I did this

```
    body['fuel_fee'] = int(rows[a][23] or 0)
    body['late_fee'] = int(rows[a][24] or 0)
    body['other_fee'] = int(rows[a][26] or 0)
```

But I see that they are still being stored as strings in elastic. I want `sum`
operation on these.

I even deleted index and rewrote the entire data, so I can confirm that there is no issue of previous mappings here.

Why am I not getting these fields as integers ? How can I get this done ?

EDIT - I am fetching data from postgres database. And in postgres, these fields are stored as strings, not integers. Can it have any effect ? I think no, as I am type casting in here in python.

Answer (score 1):

The datatype of a field is determined in either of the following ways

- When you create mappings (before indexing any real data) and explicitly tell elasticsearch about the field type. In your example, the field fuel_fee will be mapped to **long** and any record containing non-integral values will throw an error
- Based on the first document indexed, elasticsearch determines the field type. It tries to convert the subsequent document field values to the same type thereafter.

Coming back to your question, how do you know that all your fields are stored as strings and not integer? Can you try `GET <your-index>/_mapping` and see if your assumption is correct.

If the problem persists, try any of the following:

- Create [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) before indexing any data.
- Index only 1 document(with kibana or through curl api) and check the mapping output again.

Comment: I can see in Kibana the type of field. Kibana says it is string.

Comment: Also, one of the reasons I am using python to push data is that elastic can get the type of every field, so I can skip making mappings. But I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: please post a detailed snippet of your indexing api so that i can help. I just tried it out and indexing an integer maps it to Long type(not string)